# jquery data tables - Server-side custom processing image is not working on paging on IE and chrome

Tags: datatables

processing image is not called on pagination jquery datatable server side

```
<script src="Assets/DataTables-1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTableDataTable({
            "language": {
                "processing": "Processing...",
                "LoadingRecords": "Processing..."
            },
        });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Processing image is showing only on Firefox when we click on pagination buttons but not showing on IE and chrome.  I am using custom processing image.

Comment: I have tried ajax start and stop event and remove processing from dataTableDataTable  like this

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            

        $('#example').append('<img src="../Images/Load.gif"/>');
        $('#example').show();

    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        
        $('#example').html("");
        $('#example').hide();

    });

it is working fine on firefox but not in chrome and IE

Comment: Check when your image is loaded in `Network` tab of your browser. It maybe requested before it was processed. Also your `datatables` initialization doesn't look like `server-side`

Comment: Hi Andzhik 
thanks for reply i havent posted full code but my database initialization is server side and it is working fine on firefox but in case of ghrome and IE processing image doesn't work in case of pagination.

Comment: Check `Network` tab of developer tools if those images are even loaded

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in chrome，you can  changing the z-index in css:

```
.dataTables_processing {
z-index: 1000;
}
```